# Mapview. Callback like zoomDidChange

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkmapviewdelegate

I want get callback, always then map did change zooming.

I try use

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
```

But it callback, when change is significant.

Comment: refer bellow links may be it will helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426203/what-event-is-fired-when-mkmapview-extent-changes

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166444/mkmapview-zoom-and-region

Comment: You mean you want to know when map region changes _while_ dragging or zooming?  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11675587/467105) by Jano.  You'll need pan and pinch gesture recognizers.